# Filter chain halted as :authorized rendered or redirected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm currently working on a Rails 7.0.3.1 application. I have a controller `ApplicationController` where I have a `before_action` filter to authenticate that a user is logged in. If the user is not logged in I redirect to the sign in form.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authorize
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_user, :logged_in?

  private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= PropertyOwner.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

  def logged_in?
    if @current_user
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end 

  def authorized   
    return if logged_in?

    redirect_to sessions_new_path 
  end
end
```

The `sessions_new_path` redirects to the log in form in `/sessions/new.html.erb` template. In the SessionsController, If a user is authenticated I redirect to the `properties_path` However, after I log in Im redirected to the login page again instead of being redirected to the `/properties` page.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authorized

  def create
    user = PropertyOwner.find_by(email: params[:email])
    
    if user&.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to properties_path, status: :see_other
    else
      redirect_to sessions_new_path,  notice: "Invalid email or password"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session.delete(:user_id)
    redirect_to sessions_new_path, status: :see_other, notice: 'Logged out!'
  end
end
```

In the line where I run `redirect_to properties_path, status: :see_other` I set `status: :see_other` since in Rails 7 is making a TURBO_STREAM request. When I look into the server I see that there is a message

> **Filter chain halted as :authorized rendered or redirected**

On the GET request to the `/properties` route. and then is redirected to the `sessions/new` path, why is that?

```
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 4.5ms | Allocations: 2893)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 7.9ms | Allocations: 6241)
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 10.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 8945)


Started POST "/sessions" for ::1 at 2022-12-29 16:51:28 -0500
Processing by SessionsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"example@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Sign In"}
  PropertyOwner Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "property_owners".* FROM "property_owners" WHERE "property_owners"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "example@example.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:5:in `create'
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/properties
Completed 303 See Other in 264ms (ActiveRecord: 9.2ms | Allocations: 10088)


Started GET "/properties" for ::1 at 2022-12-29 16:51:28 -0500
Processing by PropertiesController#index as TURBO_STREAM
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/sessions/new
Filter chain halted as :authorized rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 314)


Started GET "/sessions/new" for ::1 at 2022-12-29 16:51:28 -0500
Processing by SessionsController#new as TURBO_STREAM
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1.1ms | Allocations: 1585)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 1.9ms | Allocations: 2426)
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 2.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 2787)
```

Not sure why is redirecting to the log in page again after being redirected to properties, I never hit the PropertiesController. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you share properties controller?

Comment: `if @current_user` is always false, since you never call `current_user` to initialize `@current_user`. just use `return if current_user` and remove `logged_in?` method, it's redundant.

Comment: @Alex, this is correct. The `@current_user` never gets set. If you would like to answer this question, I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`logged_in?` is always `false` when it's called, because `@current_user` is not initialized and is `nil` by default.

```
def logged_in?
  if @current_user
```

---

Make sure to always use `current_user`:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  helper_method :current_user

  # NOTE: to avoid confusion, authorization is not authentication.
  # before_action :authorized
  before_action :authenticate

  private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= PropertyOwner.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

  # def logged_in?
  #   current_user.present?
  # end

  def authenticate
    # there is really no need for explicit `true` or `false`
    return if current_user

    redirect_to sessions_new_path 
  end
end
```